# Create Group of Controls Based on Bound Collection

Tags: c#, wpf

So I want to have a data structure along the lines of:

```
List<Question> questions
```

Where Question is an abstract class from which various other question types are derived such as:

```
class OneTenQuestion: Question
class FreeCommentQuestion: Question
...
```

On my WPF form, I then want to be able to bind this `List<Question>` to a stackbox and have it add a new `Grid` of controls for each `Question` in the list with the exact layout of this grid being defined in a method of each derived class. These `Question` objects will be generated based on a JSON file to produce question sets.

For instance, a `OneTenQuestion` would add a slider and a label whilst a `FreeCommentQuestion` would add a label and a textbox. There are several other question types but I think these examples should suffice.

Where would I even start with this? I'm transitioning from WinForms to WPF so a pointer to the right concept or indication that this isn't the best approach would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typically use data templating in this scenario (see [Microsoft Docs: Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview)). Using `DataTemplate` is a very powerful solution when you need to create controls dynamically.
A `DataTemplate` without a key (`x:Key`) is an implicit template, as it will apply automatically i.e. without explicit reference, to the type that matches the `DataTEmplate.DataType`. You should define an implicit `DataTemplate` for each  type of `Question`.
Alternatively you can use a [`DataTemplateSelector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector?view=netcore-3.1#examples), if selecting the `DataTemplate` depends on more conditions than just the data type.

Instead of a `StackPanel` you use an `ItemsControl` like `ListView`.
You can modify the `ItemsControl.ItemsPanel` to stack items either vertically (default) or horizontally:

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public ViewModel()
  {
    this.Questions = new ObservableCollection<Question>() 
    {
      new OneTenQuestion(), 
      new FreeCommentQuestion
    };
  }

  private ObservableCollection<Question> questions;
  public ObservableCollection<Question> Questions
  {
    get => this.questions;
    set
    {
      this.questions = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <ViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>
  <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type OneTenQuestion}">

      <!-- The DataContext is the OneTenQuestion item. You can bind to it directly -->
      <Slider />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type FreeCommentQuestion}">
      <StackPanel>

        <!-- 
          The DataContext is the FreeCommentQuestion item.  
          You can bind to it directly.
          If FreeCommentQuestion had a property Comment, then you could bind the TextBox to it.
        -->
        <Label />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Comment}" />
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>

  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Questions}" />
</Window>
```